# Compile glibc 2.3 with linuxthreads

Tags: 18.04, compiling, make, glibc

I'm trying to compile glibc 2.3 (https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.3.tar.gz) with the addon linuxthreads (https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-linuxthreads-2.3.tar.gz) under ubuntu 18.04. The requirements from the readme are:

- gcc (3.2 or newer)
- GNU make version 3.79 or newer
- binutils 2.10.1 or higher
- 2.2 kernel headers

Should i install an older distro or is it possible to do this task on a newer distro.
Any advice or pointers are very appreciated.

I could use the latest version that supports linuxthreads which is the glibc 2.5. I chose the 2.3 because i have already read the README.

So far i managed to install gcc 3.3. But im stuck trying to install the gnu make 3.x (3.82 or 3.79).

```
CC=gcc-3.3 ./configure --enable-add-ons=linuxthreads --prefix=<mypath>/glibc
loading cache ./config.cache
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking sysdep dirs... sysdeps/x86_64/elf linuxthreads/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 linuxthreads/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux linuxthreads/sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/pthread linuxthreads/sysdeps/unix/sysv linuxthreads/sysdeps/unix linuxthreads/sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux sysdeps/gnu sysdeps/unix/common sysdeps/unix/mman sysdeps/unix/inet sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix/x86_64 sysdeps/unix sysdeps/posix sysdeps/x86_64/fpu sysdeps/x86_64 sysdeps/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 sysdeps/ieee754 sysdeps/generic/elf sysdeps/generic
checking for a BSD compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for pwd... /bin/pwd
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc-3.3
checking version of gcc-3.3... 3.3.6, ok
checking for gnumake... no
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... no
configure: error: 
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

make must be under version 4.

Comment: Why would you want such an old version of glibc? If you're expecting 2.5 to work in 18.04, think again..

Comment: "Should i install an older distro.." yeah, as far as Ubuntu try 7.10 (gutsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i managed to compile glibc with linuxthreads. I'll post the steps on how to do it:

I use Ubuntu 6.06.2 LTS (Dapper Drake)

[live cd ubuntu dapper](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/dapper/ubuntu-6.06.1-dvd-i386.iso)

modify /etc/apt/source.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper main restricted 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper main restricted 
...
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-security main restricted 
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-security main restricted
```

to

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper main restricted
...
#deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-security main restricted
#deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-security main restricted
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make
```

download and extract:

[glibc 2.3.6](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.3.6.tar.gz)

[libin 2.3.6](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-libidn-2.3.6.tar.gz)

[linuxthreads 2.3.6](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-linuxthreads-2.3.6.tar.gz)

copy the plugins linuxthreads, linuxthreads_db and libidn to the folder glibc-2.3.6

create a build folder

```
mkdir build && cd build
../glibc-2.3.6/configure --prefix=/home/ubuntu/glib --enable-add-ons=libio,libidn,linuxthreads --without-__thread
make
make install
```

Check if the libc.so.6 actually have the addon on it.

run the shareable object
/home/ubuntu/glib/lib/libc.so.6

and you will get this output

[libc with linux threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7yxV.png)